# If $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ are differentiable and $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in\mathbb R$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable.

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ are differentiable and $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in\mathbb R$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable.

This statement is part of a MCQ question and it supposedly true. We can try and prove the result using contradiction, assuming $f(x)$ to be non differentiable which also implies $g(x)$ is also non differentiable using sum result. My query is can we use product result to say $f(x)g(x)$ is not differentiable if $f(x)<g(x)$, thereby getting a contradiction.

Comment: Hint:  $(f+g)^2-4fg=(f-g)^2$.

Comment: Quadratic formula?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @lulu Sir from your hint we get f-g to be differentiable , so by adding this with f+g we get the result , but was there any use of f(x) >g(x) ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer  Well, how do I get that $f-g$ is differentiable?  If we differentiate both sides of my equation, my right hand becomes $2(f-g)(f-g)'$.  Of course the left hand is some well defined function, but to isolate $(f-g)'$ I must divide both sides by $(f-g)$ which I can't necessarily do if $(f-g)$ might have zeroes.

Comment: I mean isnt it like as the left hand side is a function of two differentiable functions so combine it should be a differentiable function hence (f-g) ^2 is also differentiable ? @lulu i thought of this from your hint

Comment: Why we want to isolate (f-g)' @lulu ? And what i said above is correct ?

Comment: Note that knowing that $(f-g)^2$ is differentiable doesn't even imply that $f-g$ is continuous.  You can extract the square root, but you need to know how to do that (easy if $f>g$).

Comment: Example:  $f$ is $1$ on the rationals, $0$ elsewhere.  $g=1-f$.  Then $f-g=2f-1$ is $1$ on the rationals and $-1$ elsewhere.  Note that $(f-g)^2=1$ so it is certainly differentiable, but $f-g$ isn't continuous anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the example , i posted a question regarding this question . @lulu . I understood the fact needed of f(x) -g(x)to be either ><=0 _(i). But i still didnt get why after differentiating we are isolating terms , though in another way i got the condition (i) as you described later , but how does it relate to isolate thing ?