# Condition requiring for $f(x)-g(x)$ to be differentiable

Tags: integration

If given that $[f(x) - g(x)]^2 = F(x)$ _(i) is differentiable in $(a,b)$ , what conditions would make the $f(x) - g(x)$ surely differentiable ?.

> My thoughts as given as an example here by  @lulu [If $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ are differentiable and $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in\mathbb R$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3836231/1021792)   of drichlet type function and its variant we can observe $(f-g)^2 = 1$ ,but $f-g$ is $- 1$ over non rationals and $f-g$ is $+1$ on rationals. So if consider that $f(x) > g(x)$ _(ii) for all x also given to us ) from (i) we get $f(x) - g(x) = \pm$√{F(x)} for all x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ now from (ii) we can say that $f(x) - g(x)$ is positive therefore we will reject the $-√{F(x)}$ and hence $f(x) - g(x)$ will be differentiable all over $x$ in Reals ? Though i didnt finish the proof of differentiablity , i just avoid the discontinuity in values (changing from negative to postive suddenly and viceversa) , can anyone show after that what finishes the proof ?

Comment: the condition that make a function differentiale is that it is differentiable

Comment: I mean as in without that differentuability being stated : indirectly like i did f(x) >g(x) one condition , pleaae once check the link post , i think you will understand what i actually meant @Masacroso

Comment: You are basically asking if $h^2$ is differentiable, when is $h$ differentiable. That would be a little less cumbersome to deal with.

Comment: I mean these types of questions are valid, but really you're asking if there is a "nice" or "convenient" condition which guarantees that $f-g$ is differentiable if $(f-g)^2$ is differentiable. One such condition is that $f$ and $g$ are both identically zero. I don't think you will find any straightforward necessary *and* sufficient condition though.

Comment: One sufficient condition might be "$f - g$ is continuous and whenever $F(x_0) = 0$, we have $F(x_0 + h) = o(h^2)$", which doesn't seem too strenuous... Alternatively, if $f - g > 0$ is guaranteed, then we have $f - g = \sqrt F$, which is differentiable by the chain rule, since $F$ is never $0$.